# Current time in an Ubuntu under vmware is usually incorrect

Tags: 14.04, vmware, time, vmware-player

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 inside Vmware Player. However, Ubuntu doesn't seem to check for the current time. The time is usually off when I restart the virtual machine.

*How can I fix this so it will check the time each time I start the VM?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the VM, create a file `/etc/cron.hourly/ntpdate` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

[<sub>Source</sub>](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime)

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0 and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Does ".daily" mean the script will only run once a day? That is insufficient since time in the virtual machine runs much slower.

Comment: My bad: my machine is set this way and I just copy-pasted...  Answer edited to hourly to reflect your use case.  ;-)